# Number of solutions to $f(x)\equiv 0 \mod(11\cdot 19^{2})$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem

I have been asked to explain why the number of solutions of the polynomial congruence $f(x)\equiv 0 \mod (11\cdot 19^{2})$ cannot be 121, where $f(x)=x^{10}+10x^{8}-17x+12$.

Any ideas?

Comment: At the moment I cannot see how to do this without either a lot of computation or Hensel's Lemma. Are you familiar with that?

Comment: Number of solutions $\mod 11\cdot 19^2$ is a product of numbers $\mod 11$  and $\mod 19^2$. But number $\mod 11$ cant be more then 10, then it can be equal only 1. But it is true, only $9 \mod 11$ is a solution.